# How to clean data in terminal automatically?

Tags: terminal, command, command-prompt, data-cleaning

I wrote a small piece of code that retrieves 24/7 stock market data.
I run it in Command Prompt (Windows 11).

I'm worried that if I keep running like that, one day, my computer's memory will be full.

So I want to ask is there any way for the program to automatically delete yesterday's data?

I mean, is there a way to make the program print only 24 hours of data
to the screen?

Thanks a lot!

I tried to find some code to do that but couldn't find it!